# Count number of words more than 2 characters in a cell range in excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

How to count how many words more than 2 characters in a range of cells in Excel, we can use below formula to count total number of words with any length with counting the spaces between the words.

```
=SUM(IF(LEN(TRIM(M3))=0,0,LEN(TRIM(M3))-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(M3," ",""))+1))
```

But how to sepcify to count only words more than 2 characters.

For below example:

```
KNPC
Techn. P
16
in / out 
L
```

It should return only 3 words as word count.

[image]

To make sure to count 0 if the cell is empty.

```
IF(LEN(TRIM(M3))=0,0,COUNTA(FILTERXML("<t><s>"&SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(M3,CHAR(10)," "),"&","&amp;")," ","</s><s>")&"</s></t>","//s[string-length(.)>2]")))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For example:

[image]

Formula in `B1`:

```
=COUNTA(FILTERXML("<t><s>"&SUBSTITUTE(TEXTJOIN(" ",,A1:A5)," ","</s><s>")&"</s></t>","//s[string-length(.)>2]"))
```

---

Edit: Seems you interested in a singel cell holding words. Therefor the next example:

Formula in `B1`:

```
=COUNTA(FILTERXML("<t><s>"&SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(A1,"&","&amp;")," ","</s><s>")&"</s></t>","//s[string-length(.)>2]"))
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you JvdV. It works fine for the above text, but when I tried with different text it gaves uncorrect result: Text: "KNPC
New Refinery Project Utilities and Offsites 
  ENGINEERING
 (Specifications & Reports)
NRP/EPC-0033
Volume 6 of 14"
Above text in one cell.
It show count as 1.

Comment: @HaithamSakr, could you update your OP with a screenshot or markdown sample data? Right now I can't see why it wouldn't work.

Comment: I have added the image to tha main post.

Comment: I'm confused with what you are after now. Can you include your wanted result and also ***why*** that result? @HaithamSakr

Comment: These excels comes form a data entry operators, who charges for typing per word, but words less than 2 characters not counted, so we are trying to get the count for all words that have 3 characters and more. @JvdV

Comment: Thank you JvdV, it works perfect, just one issue, it considers the space as the seprator to split the words, but if the words in the cell in multible lines using (Alt+Enter) it consider the last word in the line and first one in next line as one word which gives not accurate results, can we adjust the formula to consider line break also as split point?

Comment: @HaithamSakr, yes, use a nested `SUBSTITUTE()` function to change `CHAR(10)` to `" "`. Don't forget....if the answer works for you you could accept/upvote it to return the favor

Comment: Thank you JvdV, I would appreciate to edit the function to add the nested SUBTITUTE() function as I am not familiar with these functions.

Comment: @HaithamSakr: `=COUNTA(FILTERXML("<t><s>"&SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(A1,CHAR(10)," "),"&","&amp;")," ","</s><s>")&"</s></t>","//s[string-length(.)>2]"))`

Comment: Hello JvdV,
Kindly, when I tried to use same formula on a range of cells, but it did not give accurate results, can it be modified to count for a range of cells?
It was showing also count as 1 if the cell is empty, I modified the formula to check in OP to solve this issue.